# MySQL problem on importing CSV file - doesnt show errors, but does not import

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm having trouble in importing a CSV file into my database...
It just simply does not import.
Shows no errors, but when I type "select * from vendas;" and run the scrip, it doesn't appear nothing.
Can anyone help me?

```
CREATE DATABASE vendas
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

USE vendas;

CREATE TABLE venda (
    regiao CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    estado CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    municipio VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    revenda VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cnpj varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    produto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    DataColeta VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    ValorVenda varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ValorCompra varchar(20) NULL,
    unidade VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    bandeira VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );
CREATE TABLE revenda (
    cnpj SMALLINT PRIMARY KEY,
    regiao VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    estado VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    municipio VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    revenda VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE produto (
    id_produto SMALLINT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    produto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    ValorVenda FLOAT NOT NULL,
    unidade VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    bandeira VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE dados_adicionais (
    id_dados SMALLINT NOT NULL UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DataColeta DATETIME NULL,
    ValorCompra FLOAT NULL
    );


LOAD DATA INFILE '/2018-2_CA.txt'
INTO TABLE venda
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Here's the CSV file i'm trying to import.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6c8ywz19xao7vmr/769525_1326400_compressed_2018-2_CA.csv.zip?dl=0

Comment: I'll try to upload somewhere else. This is the link tge professor sent, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file inner data structure does not match importing specification.

Table structure which you want to use as destination (11 columns):

```
CREATE TABLE venda (
    regiao CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    estado CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
    municipio VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    revenda VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    cnpj varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    produto VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    DataColeta VARCHAR(30) NULL,
    ValorVenda varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    ValorCompra varchar(20) NULL,
    unidade VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    bandeira VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    );
```

First 5 lines from CSV:

```
Região - Sigla  Estado - Sigla  Município   Revenda CNPJ da Revenda Produto Data da Coleta  Valor de Venda  Valor de Compra Unidade de Medida   Bandeira
CO  DF  BRASILIA    AM COMERCIAL DE COMBUSTIVEIS LTDA   08215644000109  DIESEL S10  08/11/2018  3,879       R$ / litro  PETROBRAS DISTRIBUIDORA S.A.
CO  DF  BRASILIA    AM COMERCIAL DE COMBUSTIVEIS LTDA   08215644000109  DIESEL S10  13/12/2018  3,767   3,2929  R$ / litro  PETROBRAS DISTRIBUIDORA S.A.
CO  DF  BRASILIA    AM COMERCIAL DE COMBUSTIVEIS LTDA   08215644000109  DIESEL S10  21/11/2018  3,987   3,4581  R$ / litro  PETROBRAS DISTRIBUIDORA S.A.
CO  DF  BRASILIA    AM COMERCIAL DE COMBUSTIVEIS LTDA   08215644000109  DIESEL S10  26/12/2018  3,767   3,2929  R$ / litro  PETROBRAS DISTRIBUIDORA S.A.
```

Importing specification:

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

No commas between values - space chars used. And the amount of spaces is extremely high. And commas used as decimal separator. **Wrong triple.**

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

No doublequote chars which wraps separate column values. **Wrong.**

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Matched.

Additionally - the positional format in 2nd line (1st data line) differs from one in another data lines.

---

I recommend to adjust source data and importing query carefully. And the best way is to receive CSV file with proper data formatting.

As a palliative you may try to create parsing expressions (LOAD DATA INFILE ... SET).

Comment: Hi, so i should edit the csv before importing? Exchanging commas for dots? This was the file our teacher gave us to use, and it's being exhausting. When the importation worked workbench putted space in between all characteres.

I'm really trying to do it for like 4 days now...

Comment: I recommend: Remove 1st line, import CSV into Excel (into one column), parse to separate columns (positionally - use "text to columns"), then save to CSV separating the column values with some exotic columns separator which is not present in the data (`|`, `~` or something else). Additionally convert absent numeric data before `R$` with zeros. PS. I cannot do this (despite the fact that it is not difficult) because I even cannot define columns borders.